# Compose HorizontalPager override swipes to simulate wrap-around

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using the 1.4.0-rc01 Compose `HorizontalPager` and I need the user to be able to be "navigated" back to the first item if they reach the last page and try to swipe-left again. Same goes with swiping-right while at the initial page, meaning they should be "navigated" to the last page.

Here's what I have so far:

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
val dummyList = listOf("ONE", "TWO", "THREE")
val pageCount = if (dummyList.size >= 10) 10 else dummyList.size

LaunchedEffect(pagerState) {
    // Collect from the a snapshotFlow reading the currentPage
    snapshotFlow { pagerState.settledPage }.collect { page ->
        // Do something with each page change, for example:
        // viewModel.sendPageSelectedEvent(page)
        Log.d("Page change", "Page changed to $page")
    }
}


Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
    HorizontalPager(
        modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectHorizontalDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                change.consume()
                when {
                    dragAmount < 0 -> {
                        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch { /* right */
                            if (pagerState.currentPage == pageCount - 1) {
                                pagerState.animateScrollToPage(0)
                            } else {
                                Log.d("omaga", "called")
                                pagerState.animateScrollToPage(pagerState.currentPage + 1)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    dragAmount > 0 -> { /* left */
                        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
                            if (pagerState.currentPage == 0) {
                                pagerState.animateScrollToPage(pageCount - 1)
                            } else {
                                Log.d("omaga", "called 2")
                                pagerState.animateScrollToPage(pagerState.currentPage - 1)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        pageCount = pageCount,
        state = pagerState,
        beyondBoundsPageCount = 1
    ) { page ->
        Text(dummyList[page])
    }
    Spacer(Modifier.height(20.dp))
    PagerIndicator(
        totalIndicators = pageCount,
        selectedIndex = pagerState.currentPage
    )
}
```

PagerIndicator.kt:

```
@Composable
fun PagerIndicator(
    totalIndicators: Int,
    selectedIndex: Int,
    selectedColor: Color = colorResource(id = R.color.homepage_indicator_selected_color),
    unSelectedColor: Color = colorResource(id = R.color.form_field_border_color),
) {

    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {

        items(totalIndicators) { index ->
            val color = if (index == selectedIndex) selectedColor else unSelectedColor

            if (index == 0) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_home),
                    contentDescription = stringResource(
                        R.string.page_indicator_content_desc
                    ),
                    tint = color
                )
            } else {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(5.dp)
                        .clip(CircleShape)
                        .background(color)
                )
            }

            if (index != totalIndicators - 1) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 2.dp))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've tried using the `pointerInput` modifier, but it doesn't seem to register at all. I was also unable to find any built-in mechanism for this in the docs page, which seems absolutely crazy to me. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use `pageCount = Int.MAX_VALUE`, `initialPage` half of that and then map pager index to an actual index of your list. You can example here: https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/v0.29.2-rc/sample/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/sample/pager/HorizontalPagerLoopingSample.kt

Comment: @JanBína I know I am a bit late, but could you post your comment as an answer so that I can select it as the accepted one?